# Repeating steps again with the new data in nightwatchjs

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a csv data. I want to repeat each steps except the read csv step in the nightwatchjs then execute those steps with each line of csv. How that can be possible with nightwatchjs?

Steps are like

```
module.exports =
  {
    "ReadCsv" : function(client) {
        // This will have an array of csvData
    },
    "StepOne" : function(client) {
      //Code goes there...
    },
    "StepTwo" : function(client) {
      //Code goes there...
    },
    "StepThree" : function(client) {
      //Code goes there...
    },
  }
```

I want to repeat the steps StepOne, StepTwo & StepThree with each line of the csvData so that everything can be tested. What I tried is

```
"loopUntilEnd" : function(client)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < csvData.length; i++)
        {            
            this.StepOne(client, csvData[i])
            this.StepTwo(client)
            this.StepThree(client)   

        }
    },
```

But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which I found is to use bash scripting and loop the csv data and execute the nightwatchjs until everything is finished.

My shell script will be like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
export IFS=","
cat mycsv.csv |
    while read a b c d;
        do echo "$a:$b:$c:$d";
        nightwatch -t tests/test-script.js $a:$b:$c:$d;
    done
```

And in the **global.js** file of nightwatchjs accept the csv data like this

```
CSV_DATA : process.argv[4].split(":").join(" "),
```